# Hide a column in JXTable?

Tags: java, swing, swingx, jxtable

I'm using a JXTable and I want to programmatically hide a column.

Is there any convenient methode to do this (without setting miniman/maximal/preferd width) ?

Thanks.

Comment: why-o-why do I have to write extensive api doc, if nobody reads it anyway ;-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Get the [TableColumnExt](http://download.java.net/javadesktop/swinglabs/releases/0.8/docs/api/org/jdesktop/swingx/table/TableColumnExt.html) for the relevant column from the [JXTable](http://download.java.net/javadesktop/swinglabs/releases/0.8/docs/api/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXTable.html), and call setVisible() on that.